# Alternative to voltage regulator S81250HG

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm fixing a device that is using this [S81250HG voltage regulator](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/432/S-81250HG-pdf.php) that takes **9V** as input and has an output of **5V**. But this regulator seems to be fried. I'm measuring and it gets 9V on the input but nothing on the output. But I don't have the same model to replace it and see if that is the only problem.

However, I have lying around a 5V voltage regulator: [L7805CV](https://pt.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/l78-1849632.pdf). For what I see it can also take 9V and regulated it down to 5V and it has 3 pins too (even though they don't have the same distribution, but I wouldn't connect straight to the PCB).

I was wondering if I could use this L7805CV voltage regulator as an alternative to the S81250HG or it could cause any issues. At least to see if the device turns on. And then I would look for a proper replacement.

Updating with a some more information:

The device I'm fixing is a Sony Discman D-50 (D-5 in the US). [Here](http://freeservicemanuals.info/en/servicemanuals/download/Sony/d-5.pdf) you can find a copy of the service manual.

If you check on **page 17** of this document you can see the part of the DC input and voltage regulator: [image]

And also on **page 26**: [image]

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it should work but, there may e subtleties about the usage of the original device that might cause a 7805 not to produce the right output. Show your schematic in other words.

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka. I've updated the question adding this information :)

Comment: It looks like it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
Feel free to add your answer so I can mark it as valid for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the 7805 is a bit more powerful than the original device AND there doesn't appear to be problems with low-drop-out in this application, the 7805 should be a good temporary substitute to prove the point: -

> *At least to see if the device turns on. And then I would look for a
> proper replacement.*

It may prove to be a bit noisier than the original so that is something that might put you off making it a permanent replacement. Also, the 7805 does appear to be more hungry in terms of quiescent current so, if the unit is battery powered this may also cause a problem. I couldn't check that because the link to the product is faulty.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy :)
The device only uses a power adaptor, no batteries involved.